# How to add perpendicular/transversal lines to edge lines in networkx (python)?

Tags: python, networkx

I want to add perpendicular/transversal lines to edges according to a 'weight'.

What I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':["A","A","B","B","C"],
         'B':["B","D","C","D","D"],
         'weight': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=5)
        })


for i, row in df.iterrows():
    G.add_edge(row[0],row[1], label=row[2])
    
pos = nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos , with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'label'))
```

The code generates this image:

[network showing edge weights as values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkiPB.png)

What I would want is something like this:

[network showing edge weights as transversal lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqzHt.png)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.  **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick hack, instead of passing the weight as a label, format them into a string of "I" letters joined with spaces:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
    'B': ["B", "D", "C", "D", "D"],
    'weight': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=5),
})

# ...

labels = {
    (u, v): ' '.join('I' * weight)
    for (u, v), weight
    in nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight').items()
}
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)
```

Output:

[image]